# jQuery.css('top') and IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, styles

i have a problem with IE8 + jQuery.css('top') function.

1) I have a DIV with 100px height and 600px width. I have another DIV inside the first one with style="top:50%" so it should be placed in top=50px.

2) All browsers display it correctly. BUT, later, i need to use jQuery to find the position of the element and here comes the problem with IE8:

$('#txt').css('top') returns me NOT 50px BUT 300px !!!!! which is not correct. Also i noticed that it returns always the value of 0.5*WIDTH of the parent DIV !! It makes me crazy! how could it be?

here is the code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        function onLoadTest(){
            alert("document.getElementById('txt').style.top="+document.getElementById('txt').style.top+"\n$(#txt).css('top')="+$('#txt').css('top'));
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoadTest()" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width:100%; height:100%">             
    <div id="box" style="width:600px; height:100px; position:absolute; padding:0px; margin:0px; border: solid 1px">
        <div id="txt" style="top:50%; position:relative; padding:0px; margin:0px;border: solid 1px">
            im in the position top=50% (which is 50px), plz compare to alert box data
        </div>          
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colemande/27m9A/1/). Try using offset(). IE gets weird sometimes with absolute.
Using offset is with the boarder on your parent will get you 51 so I took the boarder off the parent